# How do I pass callback function to a React component from an existing web page？

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, frontend

Say I have a React component with a button in it and I want to integrate this component into an existing web page (not built with React). Every time the button is clicked, I want to change some image on the web page. I wanted to somehow pass in a callback to the React component, and call the callback when the button is clicked so that the web page can decide whatever it wants to do when the button is clicked. Is this possible? If so, how should I do this? If this is not possible, what are the alternatives? Can I somehow raise an event from the component and have the web page catch it? I am new to front end development so let me know if I am crazy. :)

For example, the web page is some like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <image src="someURL"></image>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="theReactComponent.jsx"></script>
</html>
```

In theReactComponent.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

In app.jsx:

```
import React from "react"
export default function App(): JSX.Element {
    const onClick = () => {
        // Call the callback function here to change the image in the html
    }

    return <button onClick={onClick}>Click here</button>;
}
```

So what I want to do is passing a call back to the component App.

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or other debugging information.

Comment: I have added some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal (meaning, only very specific use cases call for this) but you can access any DOM element in the page using the standard JavaScript API from inside a React app as long as that element is present in the page at the time you want to interact with it. For example, for changing the `src` attribute of the `img` tag in your example:

```
import React from "react"

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
    const onClick = () => {
      const image = document.getElementById('image-id');
      image.src = 'new-src';
    }

    return <button onClick={onClick}>Click here</button>;
}
```

Just remember to add either an `id` or `class` attribute to your DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While this will work, I don't want to make my React component tightly coupled with a particular web page so that I can reuse it elsewhere. I figured out that I could use dispatchEvent to dispatch a custom event and have an event target implemented in the web page so that it can listen to the event and decide whatever it needs to do. Do you think this would be a good solution?